# Material ui appbar doesn't scale down when on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, web, material-ui

I have created a material-ui appbar at the top of my website like this: [Website Appbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wyia.png)

When I scale the website to a mobile size, the Appbar is not responsive to the screen: [Appbar when in mobile size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Jmr.png)

Here is the code on how my appBar is designed:

```
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AppBar color="primary" style={{ position: 'absolute' }} >
          <Toolbar style={{ marginRight: 'auto', marginLeft: 'auto' }}>
            <Button basic href="http://localhost:3006/home">
              <Image
                spaced="left"
                height="40px"
                floated="left"
                verticalAlign="middle"
                src="https://admin.neruti.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/neruti_logo_inverted_400x400.png"
                alt="logo"
              />
            </Button>

            {menu.items.map((item) => {
          if (item.menu_item_parent === '0') {
            const menuList = menu.items.filter(
              i => i.menu_item_parent === item.ID.toString(),
            );
            if (menuList.length === 0) {
              return (
                <Button
                  style={{ marginRight: '3vw', color: '#D8EDFE' }}
                  as="a"
                  key={item.ID}
                  link
                  href={`/${item.url.split(config.wp_url)[1].slice(0, -1)}`}
                >
                  {item.title}
                </Button>
              );
            }

            return (
              <div>
                <Button style={{ marginRight: '3vw', color: '#D8EDFE' }}>
                  <Dropdown item text={item.title} key={item.ID}>
                    <Dropdown.Menu>
                      {menuList.map(i => (
                        <Dropdown.Item
                          key={i.ID}
                          href={`/${item.url.split(config.wp_url)[1].slice(0,
                          -1)}/${i.url.split(config.wp_url)[1].slice(0, -1)}`}
                        >
                          {i.title}
                        </Dropdown.Item>
                    ))}
                    </Dropdown.Menu>
                  </Dropdown>
                </Button>
              </div>
            );
          }
          return null;
        })}
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
```

Do I need some extra codes to adjust the size of the Appbar?

How can I solve this problem?

**Problem solved update**

After much research and work, I have solved the problem and I would like to share the solution.

Instead of changing the style of the AppBar, I ended up creating a new header component just for mobile screen size. Then, use *react responsive media queries* as seen here [React responsive](https://github.com/contra/react-responsive) to check whether the screen is mobile or desktop to find out which header components to execute.

**Code example:**

```
  <div>
        <MediaQuery maxWidth={1224}>
          <MobileFixedMenu menu={menu} config={config} />
        </MediaQuery>

        <MediaQuery minWidth={1224}>
          <FixedMenu menu={menu} config={config} />
        </MediaQuery>
  </div>
```

I hope this solution will help anyone that is facing the same problem :)

Comment: Read this: [Responsive Web Design - Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: An alternative is to use this: https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#responsive-drawer

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and I just found the answer here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7130

You need to handle viewport in your index.html file, for example like that:

```html
<meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In nextjs 14 app router we can add this code in layout.tsx to make it responsive.

```
import { Viewport } from 'next'
 
export const viewport: Viewport = {
  themeColor: 'black',
  width: 'device-width',
  initialScale: 1,
  maximumScale: 1,
  minimumScale:1,
  userScalable:false
}
```